# My application was minimized to the task bar and it can't be restored. Windows 7

Tags: .net-3.5, user-interface, windows-7

I have a very interesting problem...
I use **Windows 7** and develop on **C#** using **.Net Framework 3.5**
When we migrate from WinXP to the Win7 we got a next problem:
Some times when we minimized our application to the task bar it can't be maximized backward. As I notice this happens when dialog window is opened.. (May be in other cases too..). It's a funny, when I clicked at icon in task bar I hear *ding, ding...* And no expected result, application stay minimized. But when I press **Enter** my application were maximized. This can be solution for internal users in our company but not for a customer..

**Do you have any ideas?**
Thanks.

Comment: Yes indeed, you have an interesting problem but without showing the code of your application I am afraid it will stay *your problem*. Try narrowing down the problem into a simple application which allows to reproduce the behavior. Then show the code.

Comment: He-he-he... I can't show you code... By the first it is too large, by the second it is a commercial...

Comment: @Yuriy, well then second suggestion: narrow down the problem to a simple application. How do you expect us helping you without providing any details about your application? We can't read your mind. All you said is *C#, .NET 3.5, Windows 7*. Do you really expect to get some help with this?

Comment: May be some of you have same problem. I think my question is clear. Application is minimized and can't be restored..

Comment: Would vote to close as too localized if I hadn't run out of votes today. Yuriy, you need to show some code or it's impossible for us to help you.

Comment: @Yuriy, so then good luck with this. Hopefully someone who has written the same code as you (which obviously is secret) and had the same problem might help you.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Yes, I'm expect some help in this. You must understand me, that this is a non standard problem. And it came with windows 7, before this we use this App more than 3 years and all were OK.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov. How you imagine to find bug in my code where solution has 6 projects, totally more than 3000 files.... Or you want that I'll show 5 lines from my code with a bug???

Comment: @Yuriy, at least you can see those files. We don't, so don't expect miracles. You have access to the source. So try narrowing down. Start removing code until you get a bare bone application which reproduces the bug. Go ahead and get to work or wait for miracles (personally I would do the first).

Comment: @Yuiry: I agree with Darin. Lots of .NET developers target the exact same configuration you mention without any similar problems. There's no real answer we can give you without seeing your code. The best place to start troubleshooting is creating a brand new application and seeing if you have the same problem. If everything works fine there, you know the problem *has* to lie somewhere within your application's code, and from there, the only thing you can do is start narrowing down the culprit by yanking out unnecessary portions.

Comment: @Yuriy We don't imagine we can find a bug in your 3000 file solution. That's why we suggest you cut it down to a small amount of code that  reproduces the problem. When you do that you'll probably be able to work it out. This is debugging 101.